# Is it possible for a regular icosahedron to have the same length, width, and height?

Tags: geometry

Can the longest length of a regular icosahedron be equal to the longest width and the longest height? Since the icosahedron is regular, this would mean its faces would still have to remain as equilateral triangles. If this is not possible, are there any ratios between length, width, and height?

As a follow up question, can we use edge lengths to determine the length, width, or height? Are there any possible equations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron#/media/File:Golden_rectangle_regular_icosahedron.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In *Elements, XIII, 16* Euclid constructs the regular icosohedron, comprehends it in a sphere, and shows that its side is irrational, i.e. incommensurable with the sphere’s diameter.

But how do you define length, width and height of a regular icosohedron? If length is the distance between opposite parallel faces, then it seems length, width and height are equal, and are equal to the diagonal of the regular pentagon whose side is the side of the icosohedron (see @intelligenti pauca link). On the other hand, if you define “greatest length” as the distance between opposite vertices, then again greatest length, width and height are equal to one another and to the sphere’s diameter.